# window.open() add a rel="nofollow" attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open, nofollow

Is there a way to add a `rel="nofollow"` attribute to the `window.open()` Javascript function?  Or is that any way to have Google not follow a link created by Javascript or jQuery.

**Update**

Also, this will be a product for a client and I will not have access to their files.  Any changes the `robot.txt` or `.htaccess` are off the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Google can read javascript links](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html)

In HTML5, the [`nofollow` link type](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/links.html#link-type-nofollow) may only be used with `a` and `area` elements.

Since you are already using javascript.. (and can not access the `robots.txt` or `.htaccess` files), there is no reason why you couldn't use a normal (but hidden)
`<a href="http://exampe.com" rel="nofollow"` ...etc
(something that *does* support the attributes you seek, thus clearly and 'legally' indicating intention)
and *use javascript to grab that URL (`href attribute` from the `a` element) to pass it to your `window.open` function..*  <sup>However, I do not know if google wil honor this method.</sup>

Also (regarding your updated question), you can also set those directives using a meta header tag:
`<meta name="robots" content="nofollow">`  (and set endorsed links to `rel="follow"`).

According to [this excellent **official** google explanation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en) (*do* give this a read or sit back and watch the talk..):

> **How does Google handle nofollowed links?**
>
> **In general, we don't follow them.** This means that Google does not
>   transfer PageRank or anchor text across these links. Essentially,
>   using nofollow causes us to drop the target links from our overall
>   graph of the web. However, the target pages may still appear in our
>   index if other sites link to them without using nofollow, or if the
>   URLs are submitted to Google in a Sitemap. Also, it's important to
>   note that other search engines may handle nofollow in slightly
>   different ways.

According to [wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nofollow):

> - Google states that their engine takes "nofollow" literally and does not "follow" the link at all. 
>     However, experiments conducted by SEOs show conflicting results. These studies reveal that Google does follow the link, but it does not
>     index the linked-to page, though it might be in Google's index for
>     other reasons (such as other, non-nofollow links that point to the
>     page).
> - Yahoo! follows it, but excludes it from their ranking calculation.
> - Bing also follows it, but excludes it from their ranking calculation.
> - Ask.com also respects the attribute.

<sup>PS: should anyone *know* (and be able to proof) that this wouldn't work.. leave a comment so future readers know that this workaround doesn't work as intended (and I'll amend my answer to reflect that).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the long answer.  I understand how the rel="nofollow" attribute works.  My question is how can I get the same result when using `window.open('http://example.com', '_blank');`

Comment: You are welcome (LOL, if 5 lines and 1 quote is considered 'long', I fear for the future of humanity `:)`). As I suggested in my answer: *use javascript to grab that `href`(url) from the hidden link to pass it to your window.open function..* (you were already using javascript): `window.open(hiddenLinkRef.href, '_blank');`

Comment: Wouldn't this still be no difference in Google's eyes?  Google would still see that a redirect is happening from javascript and therefore Google will not treat as a advertisement.

Comment: You wanted a way to 'legally' declare a `nofollow` on a URL (so crawlers that might respect valid markup instructions would pick this up). If you'd put the url 'directly' into the `window.open` you wouldn't have the possibility to specify that you'd want this to be `nofollow`.. Make sense this way? (Still, this would need to be tested. Also, *I think* google will 'silently' follow the links anyway.. not to mention other crawlers. But now it appears you want to HIDE a link from google (which isn't the same as telling google not to follow it)?

Comment: What I want to happen is that Google treats this link as a advertisement link.  The only way I know how to do that in HTML is by adding a `rel="nofollow"` attribute to an `<a>` tag.  I want this exact same functionality using javascript.  Since, I am only using javascript not adding an `<a>` tag to the DOM, this seems to be impossible.

Comment: One can use javascript to dynamically create an `a`-element. It is known that, since google executes and analyzes *basic* javascript, google will/should respect the `rel=nofollow` *dynamically added by javascript (on page-load)* to existing `a`-tags in HTML markup. One *might* obscure the url a *little*, let javascript create (not adding to layout) an `a`, set it to nofollow and add the `href`. Now google's script-engine should see a new link with nofollow set to it. Now you pass that link to your window opener. What I describe will work, question is: will it actually have the intended result?

Comment: Ok now I understand what you mean.  I will have to test with Google to see if the outcome is what I want. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: ***Please* report back on that!!!** Since looking at all the separate parts of info, it *seems* that if we combine them, we get this 'solution'. (Note however, google (and other crawlers) continuously change the 'rules').

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to add a rel="nofollow" attribute to the window.open() Javascript function?

No, but Google probably doesn't give any weighting to URLs opened with `window.open` in the first place.

> Or is that any way to have Google not follow a link created by Javascript or jQuery.

`nofollow`, despite its name doesn't ask search engines not to follow a link, only to not treat the link as an endorsement for ranking purposes.

Use `robots.txt` if you want to ask search engines to stay away from URLs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I have a script on my site that will redirect the user if they click on a certain DOM element.  So to use your words I want Google and other search engines "to not treat the link as an endorsement for ranking purposes".

Answer (score 0):

You could put a disallow in your robots.txt