# rel="nofollow" in links created using onclick event of span

Tags: javascript, html

My website allows users to post content with links.  There is one page which displays these posts with each post wrapped in `<a></a>` tags

To avoid nested links issue, the links posted by user in the content, will be converted to `<span onclick="window.href.location=">link</span>` so that when the entire content is wrapped in  `<a></a>` tags, there is no nesting.

Some websites claim that search engines do follow these javascript links. So, how to mention rel="nofollow" in links like `<span onclick="window.href.location=">link</span>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [window.open() add a rel="nofollow" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784635/window-open-add-a-rel-nofollow-attribute)   (You're not using `window.open()` but the answer will be the same: you can't. You'll need to remove the `<a> wrapping the whole post, instead.)